# Get Parent Category Name

Tags: category, name

I have category pages and within those are sub-category pages. Those sub-category pages have a sidebar displaying the filterable options within that subcategory. I want to echo out the name of the parent category at the top of that sidebar. I'll need to do this for each parent category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
$allCategoryIds = ALL_YOUR_CATEGORIES_AS_ARRAY;
foreach($allCategoryIds as $categoryId){
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);    
    echo $categoryName = $_category->getName()."<br />";  
}
```

Comment: That works but i'll need this to work for more than one category. Sorry, I should've mentioned that in the question.

Comment: You can loop through all your category ids and then can get names for each category. check updated answer @totneschap